# Use stored procedure with parameters in report

Tags: stored-procedures, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

How can I use a stored procedure with parameters in Crystal Reports? I'm using the following code with VS 2013, asp.net, MVC, and razor.

```
 public ActionResult AllCustomerReports()
 {
     ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
     rd.Load(Server.MapPath("\\Reports\\rpt_AllCustomers.rpt"));
     rd.SetDataSource(db.CUSTOMERs.Select(p => new
     {
         Id = p.Id,
         CUSTOMER_CODE = p.CUSTOMER_CODE,
         CUSTOMER_NAME = p.CUSTOMER_NAME,
         CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = p.CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
         CUSTOMER_LANDLINE = p.CUSTOMER_LANDLINE,
         CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = p.CUSTOMER_TYPE.Id,
         CUSTOMER_TYPE_NAME = p.CUSTOMER_TYPE.CUSTOMER_TYPE_NAME,
         LOCATION_TYPE_ID = p.LOCATION_TYPE.Id,
         LOCATION_TYPE_NAME = p.LOCATION_TYPE.LOCATION_TYPE_NAME,
         INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = p.INDUSTRY_TYPE.Id,
         INDUSTRY_TYPE_NAME = p.INDUSTRY_TYPE.INDUSTRY_TYPE_NAME
     }).ToList());

     Response.Buffer = false;
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.ClearHeaders();
     Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
     stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     return File(stream, "application/pdf", "ListofAllCustomers.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get database record in either dataset Or datatable, then assign that data to report as below. **No need to pass parameter in report** to fetch data. You can **pass those parameter in sp direct**.

```
DataSet ds = get data from database which call sp with parameter;                

string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/XXXXX.rpt");
reportDocument.Load(reportPath);

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Copy();

reportDocument.SetDataSource(dt);

CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument;
CrystalReportViewer.DataBind();
```

Comment: How will I pass parameter to SP using my datetimepicker value? And click the generate report based on the fields provided by the user.

Comment: have you used iframe to load report viewer?

Comment: No. i don't know how to use that.

Comment: (1) place your filter related controls in one view and blank div with id='divReport'
(2) define common partial view in which place iframe
(3) on filter button call ajax and load iframe partial view and assign that html to div 'divReport'
(4) in iframe partial view load one .aspx page, which hold report viewer
(5) in .aspx page write code to load report file and assign database data and load report

Comment: please refer link : http://atikpassion.blogspot.in/2014/11/aspnet-mvc-sap-crystal-report.html

Comment: is it okay to use .aspx in my Reports? if your engine is Razor?

Comment: yes, i have used the same, i think to use report viewer you have to use

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will try the link you commented above.